# ASP.NETフォームアプリケーションを使いつつAPIを作る方法

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

事情があり、MVC5ではなくASP.NETフォームアプリケーションで開発しています。
ですが、このプロジェクトの中でフォームページを持たないAPIを作りたいです。
方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

通常ASP.NET Web FormsでのWebサービス作成にはASMX Webサービスか、もしくはジェネリックハンドラー(ashxファイル)を使用します。またWCFをホストすることもできます。

Answer (score 1):

Web Formsやお使いのVisual Studioのバージョンにもよるのですが、API部分にだけMVCやWeb APIを採用する事もNGでしょうか？

例えばVS2013以降であれば Web Forms / Web API /MVC を一つのプロジェクトで共存させることは容易ですので、『画面がある機能はWeb Formsで、API部分はWeb APIで実装』ということも実現可能です。